# Visual Studio Code is not detecting version 0.10.5

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am running Visual Studio Code 0.10.4 on Windows 8.1. It is not detecting the version 0.10.5 update. Does that indicate something is wrong or is it just that the update is taking a while to roll out?

Best regards

David

Answer (score 1):

In any case you can always just download the latest version from https://code.visualstudio.com/ and run the installer over the existing version (after closing Code).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.